# window.document.execCommand() is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am trying to copy a string into clipboard using a dummy input element in my angularjs application. The following broadcast handler is called, and the input.value is set to the right value. However window.document.execCommand() has no effect.

```
$scope.$root.$on('on-share-link-made', function (event, args) {
    var input = $('#MyInput')[0];
    input.value = args.uri;
    input.select();
    window.document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Is there any error or warning?

Comment: Here is sample fiddle, where it works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/zLyjqer0/

Comment: Thank you xxxmatko. Console shows no error or warnings. Your fiddle works. So I tend to believe this has something to do with angularjs and its digest loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.document.execCommand will only work when called in an event handler such as a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your html and possibly your css. `execCommand` wont work if the input has `display: none`, `width: 0` or `height: 0`. If you are trying to copy some string in the ui, your best approach is to position the input tag using absolute/fixed position out of vision.

Comment: The input is has non-zero width and height and display is not none. I can see that the value is set and also selected. But now I check the return of the execCommand() and it returns false. I understand execCommand must be called in an event handler and this seems to be the problem.